# Wordpress - add tags or taxonomies in post body

Tags: wordpress, tags, taxonomy

How can I include the tags or taxonomies of a specific post inside that post body.
I mean not at the beginning or end of post, but inside it.

Ex:
Let's say I have a post about a movie and I have a taxonomy / tag with the director's name.
What if I want to add the director name with a link to the tag inside the post.
Is there a plugin to make that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using shortcodes feature. There is no other easy way to place some code right into the middle of post content.